# How list in STL doesn't store in contiguous memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

**When we want to print elements of list**

```
void printCollection(T coll){
    auto it=coll.begin();
    while(it != coll.end())
    {
        cout << *it << ' ';
        it++; // HERE
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

**so, when using it++ from begin to end-1 .. then list is contiguous because of moving to next addresses in memory by it++ .. Is that true?**

Comment: "contiguous" means that all items are stored in a single memory block, one after another without any gaps (basically as an array), which does not happen in case of list.

Comment: `++` does not mean adding the address by 1.

Comment: so,what does ++ mean?

Comment: it's pointing the iterator to the next element, if there's one

Comment: `++` is an overloaded increment operator. In case of list it will adjust iterator to point at next list item which can be located anywhere.

Comment: Why did you tag C++14? I don't see any features of C++14 being used in the code or question

Comment: because of "auto"

Comment: You seem to be under impression that `it` is a pointer, but's it's not. It's an iterator, a class designed specially to resemble a pointer while letting you work with storage that may or may not be contiguous.

Comment: FYI ``auto`` was not added in C++14

Comment: oh sorry.. it's in c++ 11 ,I'll edit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you increment an iterator, that simply means "move to the next item in the collection". What that entails under the covers actually depends entirely on what type the collection *is.*

It *may* be the next (or close-by) memory address if your collection is something like a contiguous vector.

Or it may be somewhere totally different if your collection is a linked list of some description.

Or it may send off a network request to your database server located in Cheyenne mountain if your collection is controlled by certain shady US government organisations :-)

Bottom line is that `iterator++`, unlike C pointers, does *not* necessarily mean moving a short distance to a subsequent memory location.

---

By way of example, the following class allows for the sort of behaviour you're asking about:

```
template <typename T> struct NodeIterator {
    // All we need is a current pointer.

    Node<T> *m_current;

    // Iterator constructor, simply stores pointer to node supplied.

    NodeIterator(Node<T> *current): m_current(current) {
    }

    // Pre-increment: advance, return it.

    const NodeIterator &operator++() {
        m_current = m_current->next;
        return *this;
    }

    // Post-increment: save current, advance, return saved.

    NodeIterator operator++(int) {
        NodeIterator result = *this;
        m_current = m_current->next;
        return result;
    }

    // Dereference iterator.

    T &operator*() { return m_current->val; }
};
```

You can see from the `operator++` overloads that it's *not* just a simple "add a few bytes" to the current address, it actually advances the pointer through the list.

Just keep in mind that's from memory, I *think* I've done it right but you may want to consider it just an indication of how things could work rather than production-ready, bullet-proof code :-)

Comment: so, iterator moves within it's container only not order of addresses in memory.. that's right?

Comment: @AhmedElemam, yes, *how* it moves through the container is up to the container. I've added some code that will (hopefully) make things clearer.

Comment: that is true in a list, but for example in a vector the memory is contiguous, it depends on the container that is used.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks but please,why it doesn't true when we say // while(it < coll.end()) instead of //while(it != coll.end())??